# memory allocation problems with CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, memory

i still have a problem with the mempry usage of Cake. I read alot of threats and tried out like 1000 things but nothing really help.
I use CakePHP 2.4.x. Working with a MySQLdB. I wrote an API to select log-data from the database. I does a Test to explain what confusing me that much. I've a select which returns 1400 rows with 11 columns. My general memory usage (using memory_get_usage) is about 4MB.
After i select with that:

```
$condition = array('conditions'=> array(


    'LogBackend.created_at between ? AND ?' => array(
                                            $this->params['url']['from'],$this->params['url']['to']
                                       )));

    $this->data = $this->LogBackend->find('all', $condition).
```

My memory usage just explode to more than 9MB. There is still no return or any work with the Data at all. Just the select. Well 9MB are not that much but if i select more, like it should be possible round about 100k rows. My 256MB just run out of space. 
Can anybody tell me the reason for that ridiculous memory usage?

best regards

Comment: Are you using containable behavior? And have you set `$recursive` somewhere?

Comment: Do you really need to have 100k rows in memory? cant you limit your queries to work with a limited set of data? or work with a loop selecting, handling and then clearing data as you go? This is not a CakePHP memory problem its an approach problem.

Comment: @cernunnos I agree that, depending of course on the exact purpose, this could be implemented differently. However, IMO is not without blame here. CakePHP models always return results as an array, causing the entire record set to be loaded in-memory. If, for example, OP wants to implement an export functionality, it's not possible via the standard CakePHP models. Creating a custom model/data source that uses [unbuffered queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php) may be a solution.

Comment: I dont use containable behavior. It should be a service which unloads Log-Tables from a Online-Banking. I dont need 100k rows in memory. I just need to select those and put it in a csv-file to return it to the user. The thing is that i cant limit my select because the user himself should have the possibility to select that range of data he want to. If i limit the queries i have to loop though those to get all Data needed for the return. i think that isnt a better solution. @thaJeztah please tell me how to do it better, i can take that blaming if it improve my skills.

Comment: @user2140111 sorry, I now see that a word was missing in my comment; I meant to say *CakePHP* is not without blame. Always loading the *entire* recordset in-memory is (imo) a problem (limitation) **of _CakePHP_, not  your code**. If large record sets are returned by the User's query, you may need to write some code that directly retrieves the data from the database (using [unbuffered queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php) and directly outputs it to the browser (possibly in 'chunks', using [`flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php).

Comment: Now i've create an own mysql connection with mysql_connect(). Like 200 times faster than the CakePHP thing. Thx alot for your hints @thaJeztah

Comment: Be careful with mysql_* functions, they are no longer maintained and will be deprecated. It's better to use PDO

Answer (score 0):

Just use paginate instead, and process your data in chunks. Cake is geared towards chunks of 20 or so rows going to a view. But often we want to produce a report based on millions of rows. CakePhp has a function called paginate, which can be tricked into doing the mysql LIMIT 100000,1000 pretty efficiently. I found these hacks by googling pretty intensely, there is some slightly different syntax for Cakephp 1.3, and if nobody posts information on Cake 3, and it changes, I will probably come back and post that some day.

```
// cakephp 2.4.1
$condition = array('conditions'=>
array('LogBackend.created_at between ? AND ?' =>
array($this->params['url']['from'],$this->params['url']['to'])));

$this->paginate['conditions'] = $conditions['conditions'];
$this->paginate['limit'] = 1000;
// could also use ['fields'] = array('filed1', 'field2'); to limit memory

/******* here is where we trick paginate to iter in the ctrlr *****/
$this->request->params['named']['page']=1;
$this->request->params['paging']['ModelName']['nextPage'] = true;
// get chunks
while ($this->request->params['paging']['ModelName']['nextPage']) {
    $Rows = $this->paginate("ModelName");
    // boil down this chunk of data 
    $this->request->params['named']['page']+=1;
}
```

It doesn't make sense to pass millions of rows back to a view. The while loop will overwrite $Rows each time, re-using that core memory. So the challenge is to find a clever way of distilling your data, or writing a new table during the loop to be used in the next pass of your refinement. Execution is still slower on Cakephp due to model processing overhead, so if there are a lot of unneeded columns, use paginate['fields'] to process only the fields you need. Fields is the same thing as columns.

PHP is really philosophically tied into Apache, so it really isn't meant for this kind of thing. It's meant to get results in 30 seconds or less and render a web page. It isn't just Cake to blame. Python and Ruby might be better, even Perl. But then you cry like a baby when you have to sift through the tools to format in html.